# How to make a pupup menu appear in the same location regardless of screen resolution?

Tags: android, popup, resolution, multiscreen

So I created a custom popup menu or tooltip that I want to appear in a particular location but I found that the popup menu appears in a different location depending on screen resolution, is there some calculation I need to take into consideration to make sure that the popup menu/tooltip appears on the same location no matter what screen resolution the tablet is?

Comment: I'm using the function showAtLocation to display the item at a particular location on screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculating offset in pixels - you obviously need to take screen density in consideration. I would look at `DisplayMetrics` first (in particular [`scaledDensity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity)  field) .

Here is how I get `DisplayMetrics`:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(metrics);


yourOffsetPX *= metrics.scaledDensity;
```

Comment: I have something like this: int[] location = new int[2];
view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
Rect anchorRect = new Rect(location[0], location[1], location[0] + view.getWidth(), location[1] + view.getHeight());

yPos = anchorRect.top;

Comment: if you are anchoring you popup to some other view (that's how I understand your snippet), then I would assume your view is at wrong position. In this case it depends how you add an anchor view to the layout (via XML or code)